# PDO, fetching content from two tables foreach statement

Tags: php, database, pdo, echo

this may seem like a duplicate but I have clicked on all the ones and tried it but it won't fix it so I thought id post my code and ask for help!

I'm trying to echo data into a table and so far the only ones that work are the replies and subject and I can't figure out why the others won't work and as stated above I have tried all PDO posts but none of them have fixed it so please can you help because I'm relatively new to PDO so want to be able to see where I went wrong.

What i'm expecting it to do is how the subject of the ticket, the date, the publisher and whether its active but only the replies and subject show so i want to know why because its confusing me.

```
<table class="ui single line table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>By</th>
    <th>Replies</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

/* Ticket Info */
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM support_tickets WHERE username = :username ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $userName);
$stmt->execute();
$tickets = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($tickets as $myticket)
{
    $ticket_id = $myticket['id'];
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM support_messages WHERE on_ticket = :on_ticket");
    $stmt->bindParam(':on_ticket', $ticket_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $getReplies = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $replyNo = count($getReplies);
    $simpleHash = sha1($ticket_id . $companyName);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><a href="index.php?t=' . base64_encode($myticket['id']) . '&h=' . $simpleHash . '">' . $myticket['subject'] . '</a></td><td>' . $myTicket[0]['date'] . '</td><td>' . $tickets[0]['from_name'] . '</td> <td>' . $replyNo . '</td> <td>' . $myTicket['status'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So you want to combine those tho queries?You could user a JOIN to combine them, also you mixed out your logics here.

Comment: why did this get voted down this why im starting to dislike stackoverflow

Comment: This is not the way you show a table, you need to show the columns and the rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated solution. For error reporting and exception handling I recommend you to read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) and [this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).

```
<?php
// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'yourDb');
define('USERNAME', 'yourDbUsername');
define('PASSWORD', 'yourDbPassword');
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');

/*
 * Error reporting. Also, define an error handler, an exception handler and, eventually, 
 * a shutdown handler function to handle the raised errors and exceptions correspondingly.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // SET IT TO 0 ON A LIVE SERVER!

/*
 * Create a PDO instance as db connection to db.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
 */
$connection = new PDO(
        sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s', HOST, PORT, DATABASE, CHARSET)
        , USERNAME
        , PASSWORD
        , [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ]
);

/*
 * Read needed variables (from HTTP POST or GET, for example).
 */
$userName = 'Example User';
$companyName = 'Example Co.';


/*
 * The SQL statement to be prepared. Notice the so-called named markers.
 * They will be replaced later with the corresponding values from the
 * bindings array when using PDOStatement::bindValue.
 * 
 * When using named markers, the bindings array will be an associative
 * array, with the key names corresponding to the named markers from
 * the sql statement.
 * 
 * You can also use question mark markers. In this case, the bindings 
 * array will be an indexed array, with keys beginning from 1 (not 0).
 * Each array key corresponds to the position of the marker in the sql 
 * statement.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
 */
$sql = 'SELECT 
            tic.*,
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM support_messages 
                WHERE on_ticket = tic.id 
            ) AS numberOfReplies 
        FROM support_tickets AS tic 
        WHERE tic.username = :username 
        ORDER BY tic.id DESC';

/*
 * The bindings array, mapping the named markers from the sql
 * statement to the corresponding values. It will be directly 
 * passed as argument to the PDOStatement::execute method.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
 */
$bindings = [
    ':username' => $userName,
];

/*
 * Prepare the sql statement for execution and return a statement object.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
 */
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

/*
 * Execute the prepared statement. Because the bindings array
 * is directly passed as argument, there is no need to use any
 * binding method for each sql statement's marker (like
 * PDOStatement::bindParam or PDOStatement::bindValue).
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
 */
$statement->execute($bindings);

/*
 * Fetch tickets (all at once) in an array.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php
 */
$tickets = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
 * Close the prepared statement.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php Example #3 Closing a connection.
 */
$statement = NULL;

/*
 * Close the previously opened database connection.
 * 
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php Example #3 Closing a connection.
 */
$connection = NULL;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>STO answer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="ui single line table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Created</th>
                    <th>By</th>
                    <th>Replies</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
                    $ticketId = $ticket['id'];
                    $ticketSubject = $ticket['subject'];
                    $ticketDate = $ticket['date'];
                    $ticketPublisher = $ticket['from_name'];
                    $ticketStatus = $ticket['status'];
                    $ticketNumberOfReplies = $ticket['numberOfReplies'];

                    $hash = sha1($ticketId . $companyName);
                    $encodedTicketId = base64_encode($ticketId);

                    $url = 'index.php?t=' . $encodedTicketId . '&h=' . $hash;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
                                <?php echo $ticketSubject; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $ticketDate; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $ticketPublisher; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $ticketNumberOfReplies; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $ticketStatus; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably the ones that work are the ones where the parameter is a string and the ones that don't are int...

can you try:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':on_ticket', (int)$ticket_id);
```

or even (so the code is more explicit)

```
$stmt->bindParam(':on_ticket', (int)$ticket_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Why do you push him in the wrong direction, it can be solved with an JOIN.Like people user more SQL

Comment: @DaAmidza what would you suggest I do thanks like join how does that work with pdo

Comment: @DaAmidza You don't have the database structure in the question to know that and that was not the question. The question was why some results show and some don't and most likely it is because ticket_id is an INT and is being passed as a string.

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge im using pdo

Comment: Please check which ticket is is being passed. Test it the query in the console to check if you have results.

Comment: @Jack it has nothing to do with PDO or mysqli like you can use what ever you want.The thing is that you are getting a set of results ,you can join those two tables and format it in a for loop.Explain which result you are expecting here.

Comment: @Jack also your code is very bad, you should consider looking at some articles on how to write the code better.Since you are learning  PHP learn about MVC and some design patterns.You will benefit from it a lot, if you continue to write it like in the sample provided you will run in circles, and you wont learn much.The big problem on stack is when newbies ask questinos is that people give them answers for points, but they just solve your issue in a code base which is horrible.

Comment: @DaAmidza i have edited the question which my expected outcome

Comment: @Jack show thise two tables, and write example data of what you expect in the result, since your question is poorly structured.

Comment: @DaAmidza the table is put on