# Sample PDO Query don't work

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a simple SQL query that is not working. I have tried everything I know to fix this query, but to no avail.

```
$Data = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE");
```

The table on the database exists, and the connection to the database is set properly.

I have also tried this:

```
$Data = $connection->prepare("SELECT ID FROM EXAMPLE WHERE EXAMPLE1=:EXAMPLE1 ");
$Data->execute(array(
   ':EXAMPLE1' => $EXAMPLE1,
));
```

Comment: Are you sure you have "tried everything"? Seems unlikely when the code you supplied is probably actually working as expected

Comment: What are you doing with `$Data` later?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I am trying to fix this problem since 5 hours ago.

Comment: Check out this documentation https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If not, you can run an `if` check: `if ($Data=$connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM ADS")) { ... }`

Comment: @chris85 I have this if ($Data->rowCount()>0){  ......                                                            }

Comment: Don't use `rowcount` for selects. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php `If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.`

Comment: @Samuel It give no errors, also with the error cathchers this is the strange thing.

Answer (score 0):

If your connection is fine..

```
$Data=$connection->prepare("SELECT ID FROM EXAMPLE WHERE EXAMPLE1 = :EXAMPLE1");
$Data->execute(array(
   ':EXAMPLE1' => $EXAMPLE1,
));
$result = $Data->fetchAll();
```

Or

```
$result = array();
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM EXAMPLE WHERE EXAMPLE1 = {$EXAMPLE1};";
foreach ($connection->query($sql) as $row) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: mm check your connection http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php
And then execute your query in phpmyadmin or administration interface or use console sql and execute your query.

Comment: User privileges?

Comment: So, if not exist error in the logs, the connection it's fine and the permissions of user are correct, database, table and registers are exists.. i don't know bro that can be the error :(  but try to use errorInfo after prepare() - http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: I would remove the second snippet. Using a prepared statement with bound variables is ***always*** better. What if it's a string, then you need to quote it. What if the string has a quote in it?

Comment: @Cuchu Never surrender!

Comment: @Cuchu After about 8 hours of search i discovered that cloudflare was the problem... i refreshed the cache and it worked!!

Comment: @U.MJG You really need to apply proper validations and exception handlings. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012971/pdo-fetching-content-from-two-tables-foreach-statement/46019824#46019824) and you'll be surprised to find out that you would have saved about 7 hours of 8 :-) Hopefully. Good luck!

Comment: @aendeerei nice answer!!

Comment: @U.MJG Thanks. If you're interested in a complete solution, here's my [db adaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014772/return-multiple-response-data-in-one-response/46018999#46018999) (the "EDIT" part), so that you can make use of the whole data access operations in a much easier way. Bye. P.S: the PDO instance, e.g the connection, should be created outside and passed as constructor argument into db adapter - that's the perfect OOP implementation.